# Having python package and module of same name

Tags: python

Imagine I have a python package called **foo**, inside are many modules **bar1**, **bar2**...

I can access its functions after calling

```
import foo
```

and then with

```
foo.bar1.some_function()
```

Now there are a few functions that are general for the whole package **foo**. I would like to access it as module **foo**, that I can call its functions with

```
foo.some_often_used_function()
```

but then **foo** would be a module and not a package, it can't be both at the same time.

Is there some workaround to enable this syntax? Using python 3.11

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is \_\_init\_\_.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue by writing the functions direclty in **init**.py. Or in **init**.py

```
from foo.foo import *
```

and then have the functions in

```
foo/foo.py
```